# How do I figure out the typescript signature of a callback for a library?

Tags: typescript

I'm making a Typescript application that uses the JavaScript `request` library. On github, I don't see a Typescript implementation, however, there is a package `@types/request` that I've installed.

I'm not sure what to do with these types. `request()` accepts a callback, but where is the function signature typically documented for a third-party library?

I'm confused, because it seems I can use any types I want in the callback, and my code works fine:

`request("https://example.com", (response: bogusType, html: bogusType) => {
  // No errors.
}`

So my question is a three-parter:

1. If a library is only implemented in JavaScript, should I just by using the `object` type for these arguments?
2. If so, what is the point of the `@types/request` module?
3. Are libraries these days implemented in both typescript and javascript? Do I need to be looking for Typescript versions of libraries to get the correct source code and documentation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `@types/request` correctly installed and imported and you "jump to definition" on the word `request` in your call to `request(...)`, you should see the following call signature in `@types/request/index.d.ts` highlighted:

```
(uri: string, callback?: RequestCallback): TRequest;
```

If you then jump to the definition of `RequestCallback`:

```
type RequestCallback = (error: any, response: Response, body: any) => void;
```

That's the callback signature.  You should be getting full type checking against this signature, although note that two of the parameters have type `any`.

Why you didn't get an error would depend on the definition of `bogusType`.  If for example `bogusType` was an empty interface, `interface bogusType {}`, then a callback that accepts two `bogusType` can be used where any callback that accepts two parameters is expected, because regardless of the actual types of the two parameters, they can always be converted to `bogusType` (which has no members).  If you define something like `interface bogusType { x: string; }`, then you should get an error.

Comment: Thank you! FYI—I used "number" as my bogus type. Code ran fine. Is that weird?